# how to fetch data group by day, week or month in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a field "time" in my trade collection, it has thousand of entries from 2018 to 2021. I need to fetch data based on day, week and month.
Following query is working fine for minutes -

```
groupBy = {
                    "_id": {
                        "$subtract": [
                            { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                            { "$mod": [ 
                                { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date() ] },
                                1000 * 60 * 15 //15 minutes interval
                            ]}
                        ]
                    },
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
```

but when I am trying to do the same for 1 day or 1 week or a month, it is not working. I tried following query to get group by day -

```
groupBy = {
                 "year": {
                    "$year": "$time"
                  },
                  "month": {
                    "$month": "$time"
                  },
                  "day": {
                    "$dayOfMonth": "$time"
                  }
                }
```

but it is returning only 2 records between 1 day interval. I want to fetch all records between 1 day interval.

**Update** - Here is my codes

```
try {
            const pair = req.query.symbol;
            const sDate = new Date(req.query.from*1000);
            const eDate = new Date(req.query.to*1000);
            let groupBy = {};
            let whereCond = {
              pairName: pair,
              time: { $gte: sDate, $lte: eDate }
            }
            if(req.query.resolution == 1 || 
                req.query.resolution == 3 || 
                req.query.resolution == 5 || 
                req.query.resolution == 15 || 
                req.query.resolution == 30 || 
                req.query.resolution == 60) {
            
                groupBy = {
                    "_id": {
                        "$subtract": [
                            { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                            { "$mod": [ 
                                { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date() ] },
                                1000 * 60 * req.query.resolution
                            ]}
                        ]
                    },
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
          
            } else if (req.query.resolution == 'D') {
                groupBy = {
                 "year": {
                    "$year": "$time"
                  },
                  "month": {
                    "$month": "$time"
                  },
                  "day": {
                    "$dayOfMonth": "$time"
                  }
                }
            } else if (req.query.resolution == 'W') {
                groupBy = {
                    "year": {
                    "$year": "$time"
                  },
                  "week": {
                    "$week": "$time"
                  }
                }
            } else if (req.query.resolution == 'M') {
                groupBy = {
                    "year": {
                    "$year": "$time"
                  },
                  "month": {
                    "$month": "$time"
                  }
                }
            }
        
            const project = { _id: 0, Date: "$Date", pair: { $literal: pair }, low: "$low", high: "$high", open: "$open", close: "$close", volume: "$volume", exchange: { $literal: "ABC" } };
            tradeChartDB.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: whereCond
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": groupBy,
                        count: {
                            "$sum": 1
                        },
                        Date: { $first: "$time" },
                        pairName: { $first: '$pairName' },
                        low: { $min: '$low' },
                        high: { $max: '$high' },
                        open: { $first: '$open' },
                        close: { $last: '$close' },
                        volume: { $sum: '$volume' }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: project,
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        "Date": -1,
                    }
                }
                
            ]).exec(async function (err, result) {
              
              //returning result from here
            });

        } catch (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
```

Sample JSON -

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61b72505804d9a54a0074794"
  },
  "price": 0.070991,
  "open": 0.070991,
  "high": 0.076999,
  "low": 0.069128,
  "close": 0.074985,
  "volume": 2242934.0216,
  "total": 159228.1291274056,
  "type": "sell",
  "chartType": "Chart",
  "pair": {
    "$oid": "6161a094440a61740d591137"
  },
  "pairName": "ETH_BTC",
  "time": {
    "$date": "2021-10-30T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61b72505804d9a54a0074795"
  },
  "price": 0.068637,
  "open": 0.068637,
  "high": 0.07195,
  "low": 0.059323,
  "close": 0.070991,
  "volume": 3135993.3945,
  "total": 215245.17861829652,
  "type": "sell",
  "chartType": "Chart",
  "pair": {
    "$oid": "6161a094440a61740d591137"
  },
  "pairName": "ETH_BTC",
  "time": {
    "$date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61b72505804d9a54a0074796"
  },
  "price": 0.06873,
  "open": 0.06873,
  "high": 0.07955,
  "low": 0.066525,
  "close": 0.068637,
  "volume": 3610633.5753,
  "total": 248158.845630369,
  "type": "sell",
  "chartType": "Chart",
  "pair": {
    "$oid": "6161a094440a61740d591137"
  },
  "pairName": "ETH_BTC",
  "time": {
    "$date": "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61b72505804d9a54a0074797"
  },
  "price": 0.06104,
  "open": 0.06104,
  "high": 0.073242,
  "low": 0.061035,
  "close": 0.068734,
  "volume": 3912567.58,
  "total": 238823.1250832,
  "type": "sell",
  "chartType": "Chart",
  "pair": {
    "$oid": "6161a094440a61740d591137"
  },
  "pairName": "ETH_BTC",
  "time": {
    "$date": "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61b72505804d9a54a0074798"
  },
  "price": 0.062875,
  "open": 0.062875,
  "high": 0.069138,
  "low": 0.057031,
  "close": 0.06104,
  "volume": 3599095.838,
  "total": 226293.15081425,
  "type": "sell",
  "chartType": "Chart",
  "pair": {
    "$oid": "6161a094440a61740d591137"
  },
  "pairName": "ETH_BTC",
  "time": {
    "$date": "2021-07-02T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share sample dataset and the corresponding expected output

Comment: @ray - I want to display candle chart based on week, day and month data. for example - https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/

Comment: I mean the community here will probably need your json data and the expected output to see how we can help you to construct the query to get the data you need.

Comment: @ray - I have updated my question with more details, I hope it will help you to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Would [this demo of $setWindowsField](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-mrqN9aq69J) be what you are looking for? It demos the usage of partitioning by month.